# What is "KDV" in antivirus databases?

Tags: malware, virus, antivirus

I scanned a file (virus) on VirusTotal and 3-5 antivirus labelled it as Generic.KDV.549626

Is there any central "KDV" database where all the entries related to a virus are stored?

Comment: It stands for Keylogger, Downloader or Virus I've been told. Better known as Heuristic Detection basicly it is saying: "Dont have a clue but you don't want it".

Comment: a possible trojan

Answer (score 1):

Each anti-malware company develops their own databases for this kind of thing. You would have to look up that entry on each vendor's db in order to better understand what it is.